# difference between two shapefile of one place

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I've two shapefile of one place. But they are not compatible. Actually when I add both of them into arcmap at the same time, there are difference between objects such as roads, parcels and etc. What is problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that they are in the same Coordinate System?

Comment: Are they from two different sources? Are they drawn differently, or just shifted off of one another?

Comment: I've checked both layers. They are in the same coordinate system. They are from two different sources, but I dont know which one is reliable.

Comment: If they are from two different sources, you need to make the call on which is more reliable. Whether that decision comes from more details from its source location or which dataset has more valuable information needed in order to solve your problem/project.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Editing Tools, you can find a Conflation Toolbox. These tools only work with linear features or Polylines. I would test Generate Rubbersheet Links and Rubbersheet Features. Conflation is a technique to match one feature class to another feature class. It is slightly different than just snapping. You need an Advanced License to execute the Conflation tools.